# É possível fazer um loop com "0" a esquerda no PHP?

Tags: php, for, auto-incremento

Caros Devs, estou tentando utilizar uma lista com zero a esquerda utilizando **for** e **str_pad,** mas não estou conseguindo obter a variável com o 0 a esquerda, a primeira variável vem completa mas no autoincrement ele esta contando sem os digitos, poderiam ajudar?
O código atualmente esta da seguinte maneira:

```html
<?php
for($x = str_pad(1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); $x < str_pad(1000, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); ++$x) {
    echo "O X é: ".$x."<br/>";}
```

Comment: Está bem confuso. PHP não tem auto incremento, então está envolvendo banco de dados, mas a pergunta não fala nada disso. Auto incremento é número, então não faz sentido ter zeros na esquerda. Se quer fazer outras coisa precisa especificar com todos os detalhes, provavelmente nem é para fazer o que está querendo. OU é, mas o contexto é outro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente alterar a lógica, faça um loop de 1 até 1000(como já está sendo feito, sem o `str_pad`) e no seu `echo` é feito a formatação do texto.

```
<?php
for($x = 1; $x < 1000; ++$x) {
    echo "O X é: ".str_pad($x, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)."<br>";
}
```